# Apache Camel Read only First Line

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I have a requirement where in i have to push files on directories dynamically based on their contents.

The information related to the directory is available in the first line of the File.

As the files are very large in size, loading the entire contents of the file will not be suitable.
 Also i want to skip the rest of the file once the first line is read. Following is the code that i have written

```
    from("file:D:\\camel\\input?recursive=true&delete=true")
            .split().tokenize("'",1)
            .process(new CustomProcessor())
            .to("file:D:\\camel\\output\\${header.foldername}");
```

The issue with the approach is that camel parses the entire file. Also the destination gets only the line that is being tokenized at the output folder rather than the entire file contents.

Please assist

Comment: Use a processor and use streaming to read only the first line.

Comment: HI Souciance could you please share some sample code, as how do  i get the file name to be used in the stream as i have a list of files in the directory and the names are dynamic

Comment: You can get the file name from Camel as it is header. Then use java 8 streaming to read the first line. There should be a lot of examples online.

Comment: Hi i tried that option, but i am unable to read the file via java streaming in the processor as the file is locked by Camel hence throws an exception

Comment: Just grab the file from Camel as either java.io.File, InputStream or FileInputStream from the Camel Exchange Message body, and you should be able to read the first line. Camel does not lock the file when its from the same JVM process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @claus and @Souciance for your feedback. Actually i had another challenge many of the files i received did not have '\n' or '\r' as delimiter hence even reading a single like could be like reading the entire file.  I implemented the solution using the scanner with delimiter as follows.

My Router is defined as follows

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:D:\\camel\\input?recursive=true&delete=true")
            .process(new CustomProcessor())
            .recipientList(header("foldername"));

}
```

Processor Code is

```
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         File data =  exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(data,"UTF-8");
        sc.useDelimiter("'");
        String folderPath="";
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            String line = (String) sc.next();
         //business logic
           break;

       }
          sc.close();
         String destDir = "file:D:\\camel\\output\\"+folderPath;
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("foldername",destDir);

     }
```